# Unity3D Convert Key Event to plain text

Tags: unity3d-gui, unity-game-engine

I am implementing a virtual console for my game and I am piping Key up events thro an event pipe (Observable Subject) and handling them on the virtual console side with

```
public void ReceiveInput (Event e)
{
    Debug.Log ("ReceiveInput: " + e.ToString ());
    if (e.keyCode == KeyCode.Backspace) {
        if (ConsoleInputLine.LineText.Length > 2)
            ConsoleInputLine.RemoveLastChar ();
        return;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == KeyCode.Return || e.keyCode == KeyCode.KeypadEnter) {
        ConsoleInputLine.LineText = "$ ";
        return;
    }
    var chr = e.keyCode.ToString ();
    if (e.capsLock || e.shift)
        chr = chr.ToUpper ();
    else
        chr = chr.ToLower ();
    ConsoleInputLine.AppendText ("" + chr);
}
```

While this works for simple A-Z and a-z letters, when you get to the numbers and other characters I will get the raw key name, such as "Alpha1" for the horizontal "1" key above the "Q" key, "Alpha2" for the "2" above "W", etc.

Is there a way to easily get the "rendered" text out of the key events without building a switch of all the possible keycode results?

PS: I forgot to mention that, shift+Alpha1 is "!" in US Querty, shift+Alpha2 is "@", etc, but it will differ in keyboards of different countries and its not feasible to make switch statements for every keyboard in the world.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do what you want within Unity - it just doesn't know about localized keymaps. They implemented a similiar switch statement in their own UI code - which you can see how they add text to an input field starting at line 844 https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/fadfa14d2a5cb8d6462db067e669b4b2bc11a018/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/InputField.cs?at=4.6&fileviewer=file-view-default#InputField.cs-844

Comment: On line 972 they are actually getting the character from it. However, mine is always empty for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***This is not the correct answer!!!***

*Leaving it here in the spirit of assisting further research or get someone out of a jam.*

For US Querty only keyboards, this works for now, until someone replies with a proper answer :

```
public static char ToChar (this Event e)
{
    var key = e.keyCode;
    char c = '\0';
    if ((key >= KeyCode.A) && (key <= KeyCode.Z)) 
        return (char)((int)((e.shift || e.capsLock) ? 'A' : 'a') + (int)(key - KeyCode.A));
    if ((key >= KeyCode.Alpha0) && (key <= KeyCode.Alpha9)) {
        if (e.shift) {
            var specials = new char[] {'!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')'};
            return specials [(int)(key - KeyCode.Alpha0)];
        }
        return (char)((int)'0' + (int)(key - KeyCode.Alpha0));
    }
    if (key == KeyCode.Space)
        return ' ';
    if (key == KeyCode.Quote)
        return (e.shift) ? '"' : '\'';
    if (key == KeyCode.LeftBracket)
        return (e.shift) ? '{' : '[';
    if (key == KeyCode.RightBracket)
        return (e.shift) ? '}' : ']';
    if (key == KeyCode.BackQuote)
        return (e.shift) ? '~' : '`';
    if (key == KeyCode.Backslash)
        return (e.shift) ? '|' : '\\';
    if (key == KeyCode.Equals)
        return (e.shift) ? '+' : '=';
    if (key == KeyCode.Minus)
        return (e.shift) ? '_' : '-';
    if (key == KeyCode.Semicolon)
        return (e.shift) ? ':' : ';';


    if (key == KeyCode.Comma)
        return (e.shift) ? '<' : ',';
    if (key == KeyCode.Period)
        return (e.shift) ? '>' : '.';
    if (key == KeyCode.Slash)
        return (e.shift) ? '?' : '/';


    // implement more
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Alpha0 should map to ')'.  { ')', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(' }